# Error Type com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.R is defined multiple times, because of aar library

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-gradle-3.0

I have integrated a third party SDK (aar file), which uses com.github.ybq.android.spinkit inside of it. This aar library, does not declare com.github.ybq.android.spinkit as gradle depency and this causes an issue, when we **try to create a release version of our app:**

**Type com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.R is defined multiple times**

Debug builds work without any issues.

What I have tried:

1. Exclude a com.github.ybq.android.spinkit from this aar file. This did not worked, because it seems that it does not support **aar files**. Here is my code:

​

```
 implementation ('example.library@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.github.ybq', module: 'Android-SpinKit'
    }
```

I know that it is a fault of library creator to build **a fat aar** with compiled library additionally. However, I can't just force them to change it...

Perhaps there is a way to somehow **exclude Android-SpinKit from that AAR library**?

Comment: did you found a solution? I'm having a pretty similar issue on my project right now

Comment: No, the library owner fixed it on their side. I could not make it work myself.